# javascript clear field value input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple form and i have this code to clear the initial value:

Javascript:

```
function clearField(input) {
    input.value = "";
};
```

html:

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="Name" onfocus="clearField(this);"/>
```

But what i don't want is that if the user fills the input but clicks it again, it gets erased. I want the field to have the starter value "Name" only if the input is empty. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're thinking of the placeholder attribute.

Comment: @remyabel If using HTML5!  But we can only hope new sites are right?  It's definitely important to know it's not supported before IE10.  Stupid IE :'(

Comment: Um..in that case, you would use something like modernizr.

Comment: How about the 'defaultValue' property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one solution with jQuery for browsers that don't support the placeholder attribute.

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);

  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);

  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur();
```

Found here: 
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: This is no longer relevant- the placeholder attribute is supported for 99.5% of users: https://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Answer (score 11):

do like

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="Name" 
   onblur="fillField(this,'Name');" onfocus="clearField(this,'Name');"/>
```

and js

```
function fillField(input,val) {
      if(input.value == "")
         input.value=val;
};

function clearField(input,val) {
      if(input.value == val)
         input.value="";
};
```

#### update

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkYHx/) of the same

Comment: This is perfect for my needs.  How would one go about clearing another field in the form? Instead of 'this' in `clearField(this,'Name');` What is the  document structure that would allow me to access all the elements of the form by name?

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want:

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6uKrW/)

- This code places a default text string `Enter your name here` inside the `<input>` textbox, and colorizes the text to light grey.
- As soon as the box is clicked, the default text is cleared and text color set to black.
- If text is erased, the default text string is replaced and light grey color reset.

---

**HTML:**

```
<input id="fname" type="text" />
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var curval;
    var fn = $('#fname');
    fn.val('Enter your name here').css({"color":"lightgrey"});

    fn.focus(function() {
        //Upon ENTERING the field
        curval = $(this).val();
        if (curval == 'Enter your name here' || curval == '') {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css({"color":"black"});
        }
    }); //END focus()

    fn.blur(function() {
        //Upon LEAVING the field
        curval = $(this).val();
        if (curval != 'Enter your name here' && curval != '') {
            $(this).css({"color":"black"});
        }else{
            fn.val('Enter your name here').css({"color":"lightgrey"});
        }
    }); //END blur()

}); //END document.ready
```

Comment: jQuery may be a bit excessive for this case.. but since you're doing it, I'd recommend setting "Enter your name here" to a variable name - much easier to update. Same idea for the colors (`placehold_text`, `color_placehold` and `color_legal` or similar)

Comment: Good point re using variables, Mr Crosby.  I will leave as is for OP to see your comments. As to jQuery, `<French Accent>` Nevair is jQuery too excesseeve! `</French Accent>` - besides, OP tagged it and I assume is alright with it. Why use javascript and type twice as much?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="Name" onfocus="clearField(this);" onblur="fillField(this);"/>
```

JS:

```
function clearField(input) {
  if(input.value=="Name") { //Only clear if value is "Name"
    input.value = "";
  }
}
function fillField(input) {
    if(input.value=="") {
        input.value = "Name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var input= $(this);    
 input.innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's question is no longer relevant- the question was asked in 2013 when the placeholder attribute wasn't well supported.

Nowadays you can just use `<input placeholder="Your text here">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder